# Solving product of two cosine terms

Tags: trigonometry, chebyshev-polynomials

I have an equation of $\cos Ax \cos Bx = c$ where $A$,$B$ and $c$ are known constants - how to solve for unknown $x$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The short answer is that you don't.

Comment: In general, numerically. E.g., Newton's Method.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ integers?

Comment: No they are floats.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment, let's look at a simple example:
$$
\cos2x\cos3x=.1
$$
We have
$$
\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1,\qquad\cos3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x
$$
so our equation becomes
$$
(2\cos^2x-1)(4\cos^3x-3\cos x)=.1
$$
Multiply out, and let $u=\cos x$, we get
$$
8u^5-10u^3+3u=.1
$$
a fifth-degree equation, and there is no algebraic formula for solving those – one must resort to numerical methods.